# Precompiled headers C++ can't rename pch.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers

I know there are a few topics about it but I haven't found the answer to my question.

So my question is in Visual Studio 2017, everytime I create a project it's created with the class pch.h and also creates pch.cpp.

I would like to change the name of pch.h to a more pertinent name but it seems to always be looking for pch.h even though I have modified all the #include references.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***even though I have modified all the #include references*** It's in the project settings as well.

Comment: BTW, you can create projects in Visual 2017 without using precompiled headers.  Looks like your issue is another reason not to use precompiled headers.

Comment: `pch.h` is quite pertinent (pre-compiled header) and is something of a standard for other compilers. It's definitely an improvement on `stdafx.h`.

Comment: I recommend measuring the build times with and without using precompiled headers.  Build at least 10 times each and average the time.  Is the time significant between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust the name of the precompiled header file in the Project Properties under Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers. 
Note that `pch.cpp` has property to generate precompiled header.
Basically you may set the properties if and what precompiled header you use differently for each file in your project.